# XML format verification

Tags: java, xml

Feels like Im about to reinvent the wheel. Im having a message payload (e.g. from a client through a socket) in XML format (in a simple java.lang.String).

Below is an example what the payload could look like:

```
<update>
    <type>newsource</type>
    <sources>
        <source>vedbyroad box 1492</source>
    </sources>

</update>
```

I want to verify that the structure of the xml document really looks like this. Feels like the correct xml tool already is available for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to validate your XML with a **schema**.

Here's an example with JAXB:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar" );
Umarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();  
u.setValidating(true);
SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(
      javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("mySchema.xsd"));
u.setSchema(schema);
MyObject myObj = (MyObject)u.unmarshal( new File( "myFile.xml" ) );
```

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you need an [XML Schema](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/default.asp) for this document. Here's a [Java-based](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2000/jw-0908-validation.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

If you *only* want validation, the [javax.xml.validation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/package-summary.html) package can be used:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
    .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("SchemaValidation.xsd"));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

If you're parsing the document to some other form, you can validate as part of that process (e.g. using [DocumentBuilder.setSchema](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema))).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is XML DTD (Documenttype Definition). Here's a [link to get you started](http://xmlfiles.com/dtd/).

Comment: DTD is obsolete. There's absolutely no valid reason to use it any more.

Comment: How would you define entities without a DTD ?

Comment: Are entities not also obsolete?

Comment: You use XML Schema Definition (XSD), as shown here: http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

use XSD for schema checking. DTD is obsolete.

If you want to know more about XSD in an easy way, you can download 
Liquid Xml Studio, it has a free community edition
http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/XmlStudio.aspx

The best thing about this company is it provides a very user-friendly tutorial for XSD.
http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Tutorials/XmlSchemas/XsdTutorial_01.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Whilst there are many people mentioning XML Schema, you may wish to look at [Relax NG](http://www.relaxng.org/) for something slightly simpler.